# does this table fit for the 2NF?

Tags: database, database-design

a student select course table.

```
 studentnumber   name     age     selected course   credit

    1             tom      23            math           5

    2              jim      20          computer         4
```

........

if the table doesn't fit for the 2NF, why and how to correct it. thank you.

Comment: This looks like homework. Please do your own homework.

Comment: no, this example is from the internet, i learn to how to design a database.

Comment: You can't expect to learn database design from stackoverflow. Take a course or read a decent book.

Comment: And do your own homework... I still smell homework despite the protestation. No one needs to do 2nd Normal Form exercises in real life.

Comment: Go back to your teacher, or post the question, "I think this is 2NF because ...".  If you are incorrect the teacher, or stackoverflow users, will help you.  A teacher's job is to impart concepts not just to teach a skill.  If a teacher teaches how to lay 2X2 bricks one will do well with 2X2 bricks but one will fail with 2X3 bricks.  If a teacher teaches the CONCEPT of laying bricks then one will do well with all bricks.  The highest (1,2,3,4,5,X) normal form is not right for every job, the important point is to know the concept of normal forms and how to appy it to the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not 2NF. This is:

Students:

```
studentnumber   name     age    

1               tom      23            
2               jim      20
```

Courses:

```
coursenumber   name      credit

1              math      5
2              computer  4
```

Student_Courses:

```
studentnumber  coursenumber

1              1
2              2
```

Because you want to break out attributes which are not wholly dependent on the originally candidate key (e.g. course and studentnumber). Said attribues were only partially dependent on the the orignal candidate key (e.g. credit was dependent on course but not student. Age and name were dependent on student but not course.). For each partial dependency, you create a new table so that the attributes ARE wholly dependent on the new candidate/primary key.

Comment: why it is not 2NF,i am a newbie. expect you can give me more detail.thank you

Comment: what's the originally candidate key can be? how should you know. maybe these questions are silly. sorry, i am a newbie.thank you.

Comment: You can determine candidate keys by finding the attribute(s) all other attributes are depend on. In this case: Name and age were dependent on studentnumber AND credit was dependent on course. That means, originally, studentnumber AND course are your candidate keys.

Comment: got it.but in the table that you designed. you didn't use the  primary key (course). thank you

Comment: A few reasons why. A simple example of one of them is: If you wanted, in the future, to change the name of "Math" to "Mathematics", this route you only have to update it in the course table (and just the one column). It would still be in 2NF if you did not have that ID and instead just used the course id/name (assuming it was always unique through out the table).

Comment: Interesting - possibly correct analysis, but it depends on a deep understanding of the way courses work.  My immediate (naïve) interpretation of 'credit' was that it was the credit the student got for the course, whereas other students taking the same course might have gotten a different credit score.  Which really goes to show that without a detailed knowledge of the meaning of the data, you can't readily tell the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough data in your sample to figure out what all the determinants are.

From what we know of students and courses, its reasonable to guess that studentnumber determines name and age, and also that selected course determines credit.  It's also reasonable to assume that (student number, selected course) is a candidate key for the table.  This is all guess work, based on everybody's prior experience with students and courses.

The correct solution has been given in another response, except that the introduction of a new data item, namely "coursenumber" is not strictly necessary to put the data into 2NF,  provided that no two courses can have the same "selected course".  Inventing course numbers is probably a good idea, however.